# C# Get Textbox value in backgroundworker dowork event

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety, backgroundworker

In my windows forms application I have a `textbox` and `backgroundworker` component. In `dowork` event of the `backgroundworker` I am trying to access value of the textbox. How can i do that? I'm getting following exception in dowork event handler code when I try to access value of the textbox:

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtFolderName' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only access `textbox / form controls` in *GUI thread*, you can do so like that.

```
if(txtFolderName.InvokeRequired)
{
    txtFolderName.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { name = txtFolderName.text; }));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
  txtFolderName.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                string strFolderName = txtFolderName.Text;
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx). Like:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
       MethodInvoker mi = delegate { txtFolderName.Text = "New Text"; };
       if(this.InvokeRequired)
           this.Invoke(mi);
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to invoke your TextBox on the main thread.

```
tb.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
{
    tb.Text = "Update your text";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
void DoWork(...)
{
    YourMethod();
}

void YourMethod()
{
    if(yourControl.InvokeRequired)
        yourControl.Invoke((Action)(() => YourMethod()));
    else
    {
        //Access controls
    }
}
```

Hope This Help.

Answer (score 0):

this is the another 2 methods i use.

```
    //save the text value of txtFolderName into a local variable before run the backgroundworker. 
    string strFolderName;
    private void btnExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        strFolderName = txtFolderName.text;
        backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundworkerMethod(strFolderName);//get the value from strFolderName
        ...
    }

    ----------------------------------------------------
    private void btnExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync(txtFolderName.text);//pass the value into backgroundworker as parameter/argument
    }

    private void backgroundworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundworkerMethod(e.Argument.ToString());//get the value from event argument
        ...
    }
```